# Node, Express - CANNOT GET route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, server

I am building an Express app and having some issues with routing. My '/' route is working perfectly, however other routes are not. I've looked into other questions people have posted and these have not resolved my issues.

I have a routes/index.js file:

```
module.exports = function(app){
  app.use('/', require('./routes/home'));
  app.use('/about', require('./routes/about'));
}
```

My routes/home.js: - WORKING!

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('app/home');
});

module.exports = router;
```

My routes/about.js: - NOT WORKING!

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
   res.render('app/about');
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I go to '/about' I see this error in the browser - 'Cannot GET /about'

Both the home.html and about.html files are located in the same views directory.

Any help here would be very appreciated!

Comment: "Not working" isn't a very good problem description. What happens when you trying to access `http://your.server/about`? Do you see any errors?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the vague description. Getting an error on the page - "Cannot GET /about". No errors in the browser console or the terminal

Answer (score 33, accepted):

let me quote from express doc:

> A route will match any path that follows its path immediately with a “/”. For example: app.use('/apple', ...) will match “/apple”, “/apple/images”, “/apple/images/news”, and so on.
>   [see express doc](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use)

this is "not working" because you set the `/about` in the `app.use` and in the `router.get`. try to request `/about/about` and you will see that this is working (just not as you wanted to)..

now just change the `/about` in the `routes/about.js` then rerun and try to request `/about` and it will work :)

Comment: Yes I see okay! Thank you. : )

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!

Answer (score 12):

Your route is set to `/about/about`.
Change `about.js` to this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('app/about');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much for the assistance.